# Can I change a JSON object that is in module.exports of a .js file programmatically in Node?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a `.js` file with just JSON objects exported. Can I read these in update the objects and write them back to the same file? How? I know how to read a `.json` file, update it and write it back.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. Yes, you can update them, but you cannot trivially write back the object literals.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar on one of my projects but instead of using a JS file I'll store those values in a JSON file. After making your modifications to the object you can do something like this

```
fs.writeFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 4), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      //handle error
    }
    else {
      //handle success
    }
  });
```

Comment: So I take it that there is no way to change a `.js` file like this?

Comment: You could do some find/replace hackery on the file but I'm not sure of a different way than that if you want to keep it in a JS file. You could also reference the JSON in your JS file too.